# Organize software distributives

Tags: macos, file-management

I use a lot of software: some big programs, a lot of small ones, plugins and extensions… Some of them are installed and I use them every day, some of them I use once a year. I store all distributives in one directory, for some software I even save multiple versions. Can anyone give advice on how to organize all those files, so it will be easy searching through them? I use Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: You probably should mention your OS/Version.  I see you tagged it as Mac, are you on Snow Leopard?

Comment: Yes I do use Snow Leopard (added this to question).

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I download software, patches, plugins, etc, that I plan to keep for possible future use, I rename the files to something meaningful.  Downloads often have weird names, and software installers in particular can have generic names.  I don't replace the original filename, but I add text to its beginning: the application name, along with any important variant information like version.

Although I primarily use Windows, this should work with any O/S.

So the installer for an application called "Fnord" version 1.2, downloaded as "setup_fv12.exe", becomes "FNORD_V1.2_setup_fv12.exe".

I formed this habit a while ago and it has paid off on numerous occasions.